# Why doesn't this limit exist? $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^3}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^3}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$$

WolframAlpha says it doesn't exist, but I don't know how to prove it. Are there any directionals that give values different from zero?

Thank you all

Comment: Hint: The thing inside the limit is undefined on two whole lines through $0$.

Comment: $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $x=y$ all have $\infty$ as limits For $x=0$, limit could be $\pm \infty$.  It looks like getting $0$ as a limit is harder.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

- $x=0 \implies \frac{x^2y^3}{(x^2-y^2)^2}=0$
- $x=t\quad y=t+t^2 \quad t\to 0^+$ $$\frac{x^2y^3}{(x^2-y^2)^2}=\frac{t^2(t+t^2)^3}{(t^2-(t+t^2)^2)^2}=\frac{t^5+3t^6+3t^7+t^8}{(-2t^3-t^4)^2}\to ?$$